# Calculate off days between 2 dates in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have a function that calculate the number of working days between 2 dates. What I want is to convert this existing function into something like it will calculate the number of holidays in month or let's say in between 2 dates.

My existing function is something like this.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetDaysWorked] (@StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
     DECLARE @dateFrom datetime = '2018/01/01'
     DECLARE @dateTo datetime = '2018/01/31'
     SET @StartDate = @dateFrom 
     SET @EndDate = @dateTo

     DECLARE @WORKDAYS INT
     SELECT @WORKDAYS = (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
                        -(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 2)
                        -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                        -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @EndDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

     RETURN @WORKDAYS
END
```

One more thing, I am unable to handle the situation in which there is some sort of public holiday in the month like Independence day or something. I have a table named calendar that handles the situation but I'm not able to integrate that here. Table structure is provided below.

```
CREATE TABLE Calendar
(
ID Int,
[DayName] Varchar(25),
Holiday datetime,
PublicHoliday Binary,
OffDay Binary,
Active Binary
);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have that `calendar` table and dont a way to use it? How is that? That is how this task ought to be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will count the number of saturdays and sundays between 2 dates:

```
DECLARE @from date = '2018-02-03'  
DECLARE @to   date = '2018-02-13'

SELECT 
  datediff(day, -2, @to)/7-datediff(day, -1, @from)/7 -- saturdays
  + datediff(day, -1, @to)/7-datediff(day, 0, @from)/7 -- sundays
```

Holidays are different from country to country.

This function will determine when Easter starts for a specific year:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[f_EasterByYear] (@Year SMALLINT) RETURNS DATE AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE
        @c INT,
        @n INT,
        @k INT, 
        @i INT, 
        @j INT, 
        @l INT, 
        @m INT, 
        @d INT, 
        @Easter DATE 

    SET @c = (@Year / 100) 
    SET @n = @Year - 19 * (@Year / 19) 
    SET @k = (@c - 17) / 25 
    SET @i = @c - @c / 4 - ( @c - @k) / 3 + 19 * @n + 15 
    SET @i = @i - 30 * ( @i / 30 ) 
    SET @i = @i - (@i / 28) * (1 - (@i / 28) * 
          (29 / (@i + 1)) * ((21 - @n) / 11)) 
    SET @j = @Year + @Year / 4 + @i + 2 - @c + @c / 4 
    SET @j = @j - 7 * (@j / 7) 
    SET @l = @i - @j 
    SET @m = 3 + (@l + 40) / 44 
    SET @d = @l + 28 - 31 * ( @m / 4 ) 

    SET @Easter = DATEADD(month, @m, DATEADD(year, @Year- 1900, 
         DATEADD(d, @d, '1899-11-30')))

    RETURN @Easter 
END
```

This function will return 1 for workday otherwise 0:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[f_IsWorkDay] (@Date DATE) RETURNS BIT AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IsWorkDay BIT = 1

    SELECT @IsWorkDay = 
    CASE
        --Exclude Saturday and Sunday (Datefirst-independent)
        WHEN DATEDIFF(d, 0, @Date) % 7 IN (5,6) THEN 0 
        WHEN MONTH(@Date)=12 AND DAY(@Date) IN (24,25,26,31) THEN 0
        --Exclude New Years
        WHEN MONTH(@Date)=1 AND DAY(@Date)=1 THEN 0
        --Exclude Easter, Pentecost and Ascension of Jesus
        WHEN @Date IN (
            DATEADD(DAY,-3,dbo.f_EasterByYear(YEAR(@Date))),
            DATEADD(DAY,-2,dbo.f_EasterByYear(YEAR(@Date))),
            DATEADD(DAY,1, dbo.f_EasterByYear(YEAR(@Date))),
            DATEADD(DAY,26,dbo.f_EasterByYear(YEAR(@Date))),
            DATEADD(DAY,39,dbo.f_EasterByYear(YEAR(@Date))),
            DATEADD(DAY,50,dbo.f_EasterByYear(YEAR(@Date)))
            ) THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END

    RETURN @IsWorkDay
END
```

You can test if a day is a workday this way:

```
SELECT dbo.f_Isworkday(date) isWorkDay, date
FROM (values('2018-02-09'),('2018-02-10'),('2018-02-11'),('2018-02-12')) x(date)
```

Advanced test giving an interval as input:

```
DECLARE
  @from DATE = '2018-02-09',
  @to DATE = '2018-02-13'

;WITH N(N)AS 
(SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))M(N)),
tally(N)AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY N.N)FROM N,N a,N b,N c,N d,N e)
SELECT 
  dbo.f_Isworkday(dateadd(d, N-1, @from)) isworkday,
  dateadd(d, N-1, @from) date
FROM tally
WHERE N <= datediff(d, @from, @to) + 1
```

Comment: That's quite a stuff and thank you for all the help but you know I was hoping something less difficult. You know we don't have Easter or these kinda days here so that won't help and sometimes organizations allow Saturday as holiday and some don't that's what Calendar table is for so I can mark day as OffDay if it's allowed and not if it's not. Also if let's say some organization says Easter is holiday then I can enter date and mark it as Off day too.

Comment: @DoonieDarkoo you can replace the parts with Easter and X-mas with other formulars. This was to give you a hint of how I did it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Function, It will work with your Calendar table too. All Active entries in the Calendar table will not be counted as working days

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetDaysWorked2] (@StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime)
RETURNS int
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tblNonWorking TABLE(dt DATETIME,dtw varchar(30))
    While (@StartDate<=@EndDate)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @tblNonWorking(dt,dtw) VALUES (@StartDate,Lower(DATENAME(dw, @StartDate)))
        SET @StartDate=Dateadd(day,1,@StartDate)
    END
    DECLARE @WORKDAYS INT
    SET @WORKDAYS=0
    SELECT @WORKDAYS=COUNT(1)
    FROM    @tblNonWorking a
    LEFT JOIN Calendar c ON a.dt=c.Holiday AND c.Active=1
    WHERE a.dtw NOT IN ('saturday','sunday')
    AND c.ID IS NULL
    RETURN @WORKDAYS
END
```